# Building A SelectCommand with a Date Value

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, webforms

I'm working on building a query in ASP.NET/ C# WebForms.  The query relies on a series of if statements as follows:

```
//start building the query, I know SID will always be defined:
string firstpart = "SELECT * FROM [ExampleTable] WHERE StudentID= @SID";

//the variable student name is a URL variable. All the other URL variables follow this logic, 9 potential variables in total, so 9 if statements in total.
if (studentname != "") {
    dsResults.SelectParameters.Add("sname", studentname.ToString());
    secondpart = " AND UPPER(StudentName) LIKE UPPER('%' + @sname+ '%')";
}
else{
    //if URL variable is empty, simply make the string empty so it is ignored.
    secondpart = "";
}
```

In the end, I add them all to the string that I'm using to build the query as so:

```
entirecommand = firstpart + secondpart + thirdpart + fourthpart + fifthpart + sixthpart + seventhpart + eighthpart + ninthpart + " ORDER BY [StudentID]";
```

Finally, I set

`dsResults.SelectCommand = entirecommand;`

The query is executed, and the result is databound to the gridview as follows:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack){
    //bind the gridview data
    gvResults.DataSource = dsResults;
    gvResults.DataBind();
}
```

Everything runs perfect until I try to add a date to the query

```
if  (sSDate != ""){
    dsResults.SelectParameters.Add("startdate", sSDate.ToString());
    ninthpart = " AND DateEntered > '%' + @startdate + '%'";
}
```

When I attempt this, I get the error 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.' On the line:

```
gvResults.DataBind();
```

I made the date part the ninth part, so it's not added until last.  As I said, without ninth part added to the string, everything works as intended.

For the record, my dates are in this format in the URL: yyyy-mm-dd.  Only looking for dates greater than that date, not concerned about time at all.

I'm really not sure where to go with this one, so if anyone has some advice, please let me know.  I'm still very new to ASP.Net, so if there is a better way of accomplishing what I'm trying to accomplish, or if you need additional information, please let me know!

*****Edit*****

Thank you to everyone for the help!  I was able to get it working now!  My big issue was the percent symbols around the date in the query string.  I removed those, and changed the datatype of the date when I first set it from URL (was string originally, but changed to datetime.  Then I removed the .toString() part from each addition as they were unneeded (they were set to string initially, aside from the date, which I didn't want to convert to string). After those changes, it provides the desired results, and works with the rest of the query string.  Your advice was invaluable, and I can't say thank you enough!

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: This is bad --> `DateEntered > '%' + @startdate + '%'"`.... all you need is --> `DateEntered > @startdate"`  <-- for dates.. HEre --> `.Add("startdate", sSDate.ToString());` remove `ToString()` add `DateTime.Parse(sSDate)`

Comment: here you act like sql server `FROM [ExampleTable]`.. But here `UPPER(StudentName) LIKE UPPER('%' + @sname+ '%')` like oracle. Sql server data is not case sensitive. You don't need `upper`

Comment: @T.S. Actually SQL Server can be either depending on the column collation, the default is case insensitive.

Comment: @NetMage I actually see `MySql` tag now. In this sense, Oracle also can be made non case sensitive

Comment: Yep, you caught me lol.  I'm a former Oracle guy trying to re-learn MySQL (haven't really used it since college).  This is good to know though, definitely gonna do some more research on this in the future!  Thank you all for the advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code you have big misconception that you operate dates as string

```
if  (sSDate != "")
{
    dsResults.SelectParameters.Add("startdate", sSDate.ToString());
    ninthpart = " AND DateEntered > '%' + @startdate + '%'";
}
```

If `sDate` is retrieved from user input in the string format, you need to convert it. YOu can use any or `Convert.ToDateTime, DateTime.Parse, DateTime.TryParse` etc. And you need to pass date as `DateTime`. In the query, treat date as parameterized `date`. Don't convert it to string. Your code should look like

```
if  (DateTime.TryParse(sSDate, out DateTime myDate))
{
    
    dsResults.SelectParameters.Add("@startdate", myDate);  //<--
    ninthpart = " AND DateEntered > @startdate"; //<--
}
```

Now this is good on all levers.

Comment: @brandoonjen Considering your `MySql` tag use ticks for the syntax `\`tableNAme\``

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal thanks. I added, it is needed. But I think, sql server adds it automatically if it is missing. I think!

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!  I had to fight with it a bit, but finally got it working!  This has been troubling me for quite a while.  My biggest issue was the '%' + @startdate + '%'" part.  Taking the percent signs off made it work!  I also removed the .toString() part from each of my other additions, as they turned out to be unnecessary everywhere (they were already strings from where they were set on the page).  Instead of setting sSdate as a string in the first place, I changed it to date.  Will update my question to reflect this.  Thanks again!

Comment: @brandoonjen the `'%' ` syntax relates ONLY to sql `LIKE` search mechanism. And applicable only to string data. What is confusing, it is when you make bad code like `integerField LIKE '%5'`, the sql engine converts everything to string implicitly and you have no errors. But your code is bad and will return bad results. Always use correct data type syntax or you will have bad performance related to implicit conversions, incorrect results, or both

Answer (score 1):

First up, the date format used by near ALL database systems is a internal date format. The external date format, and the regional settings of the computer of course will cause this format to change or OFTEN not even be known by you!

In sql server, the date format should be ISO. That is YYYY-MM-DD. And you do NOT surround dates with %.  You surround dates with single quotes.

And you should not use some DateVar.ToString. the reason of course is that the date spit out in that case will be based on the users date settings - but you do NOT want that.

So, your code should be something like this:

```
if  (sSDate != ""){
    dsResults.SelectParameters.Add("@startdate", DbType.Date, sSDate.ToString("YYYY-MM-dd"));
    ninthpart = " AND DateEntered > @startdate ";
}
```

The above assumes SQL server - but would also work for say MS-access also. So you need/want/should FORCE the date format to a standard format that sql server etc. will accept. (you don't want to use or let the user's system default settings convert to string - else you may well wind up with a date string that flips the month and date.

eg:

MM/DD/YYYY

or

DD/MM/YYYY

For do we have

05/10/2020

Is that may 10, or is that October 5th? Well, what string you get WILL DEPEND on the users date settings!!!

So, this is why you always want to force the date output string to a KNOWN and standard format - not what the users settings are. As long as that variable is a date, or declared as a datetime variable, then above should be fine.

Where difficulty can occur will depend on the user input text box. You should force it to a date control - and thus the result from that control will be a true date data type.
So, assuming the control on the web form is set to date, then you see this:

[image]

Then in code, shove the result into a actual date, or datetime var.

```
dim dtMyDate as date
```

or

```
dim dtMyDAte as datetime

then - dtMyDate = MyDateTextBox.Text

then use above and the tostring as a formatted ISO sql server date string.
```

Comment: `In sql server, the date format should be ISO. That is YYYY-MM-DD.` Don't use that - it won't work if `DATEFORMAT` on SQL Server is set to YDM for example. 'YYYYMMDD' on the other hand will always work on SQL Server.

Comment: Also, why `ToString` it at all? Why not pass the `DateTime` as a parameter?

Comment: 100% agree on using the date variable. The problem is the example posted uses a sqldatasource, and it ONLY allows and accepts strings for the 3rd parameter despite it having the 2nd dbtype setting. (if that was a sqlCommand object,then 100 if not 200% agree to use the date typed variable - but that object used in the example ONLY accepts strings for that 3rd value (don't know why???). So yes, 100% agree. Interesting  in regards to NOT using YYYY-MM-DD, and you suggest to always use YYYYMMDD? I will consider that.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about `SqlDataSource`. What a dumpster fire it is.

Comment: Yes - I can't EVER recall having used parameters on one of those. But as noted, for any provider (oleDB, ODBC, sqlProvider)? Then the parameter value of say the command object is strong typed - and as you note - don't convert to a string - let the system do this along with the dbtype having been specified.